# What are the implications of NOT marking EntityManager as @PersistenceContext

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

In an existing project I'm currently working on the Spring Boot starter for JPA `'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'` is used. I encountered some really strange code there, which somehow still works.

The `EntityManager` is used, but it's not marked as `@PersistenceContext` but rather as `@Resource`. From what I gather the `@PersistenceContext` ensures Spring reuses the `EntityManager` in a thread-safe manner which allows for the proper function of `@Transactional`.

What are the implications of not using `@PersistenceContext` for the `EntityManager`?

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ExampleService {

    @Resource
    private EntityManager entityManager;

}
```

Based on the documentation I'd expect strange things to happen like transactions being reused/nested because the same EntityManager is given to multiple calls/threads and other scary things.